# flask bad request error 400

Tags: python, json, flask

I am new in Flask development. Below is posted a request from tutorial series which I am following now. I used Postman to make a post request as shown in below. But when it runs I show an error console that:

> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not

```
 `from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request

    app = Flask(__name__)

    tasks = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'title': u'Buy groceries',
            'description': u'Milk, Bread, Pizza, Fruit',
            'done': False
        },
        {
            'id':2,
            'title':u'Learn Python',
            'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web',
            'done': False
        }
    ]

    @app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
    def create_task():
        if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
            abort(400)
        task = {
            'id': request.json['task']['id'],
            'title': request.json['task']['title'],
            'description': request.json['task']['description'],
            'done': False
        }
        print(request.json)
        tasks.append(task)
        return jsonify({'task': task}), 201


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)`
```

I will be happy if you can help me to understand the reason for error. The json request is:

```
{
  "task": {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Read a book",
        "description": "",
        "done": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this line is failing:

```
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        abort(400)
```

`'title'` is under `'task'`, so you probably want something like:

```
if not request.json or 'task' not in request.json or 'title' not in request.json['task']:
    abort(400)
```